# How can I add a link to a table in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I have a requirement to output a table using Smarty and then have the user select a row to take them to another page.

I can display the table fine:

```
{html_table cols="Job Title,Salary,Sector,Location" loop=$results}
```

which gives:

```
<table border="1"> 
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>Job Title</th> 
            <th>Salary</th> 
            <th>Sector</th> 
            <th>Location</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Dog walker</td>     
            <td>20000</td> 
            <td>None</td> 
            <td>London</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>F1 Driver</td> 
            <td>10000000</td> 
            <td>Financial Services</td> 
            <td>Scotland</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

but I am not sure if it is possible to add a hyperlink as an additional column to the table that links to a page using a hidden id.

So I would want something link this:

```
<table border="1"> 
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>Job Title</th> 
            <th>Salary</th> 
            <th>Sector</th> 
            <th>Location</th> 
            <th>Apply</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Dog walker</td>     
            <td>20000</td> 
            <td>None</td> 
            <td>London</td> 
            <td><a href="/apply/1">Apply</a></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>F1 Driver</td> 
            <td>10000000</td> 
            <td>Financial Services</td> 
            <td>Scotland</td> 
            <td><a href="/apply/23">Apply</a></td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need to modify the `$results` array before you pass it to Smarty so that the 4th element of each row contains the link as a string. There's no way to have `{html_table}` generate the link for you.

Comment: So build the html and pass it as an element of the array?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The array element should be a string like `<a href="...">...</a>`.